# Solution to second order homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the 2nd order homogeneous ODE:
$$y(x)''+\frac{2}{x}y'(x)-By=0 $$
Where $B$ is a constant. Since I am a bit rusty with analytical solutions, I plugged it in MatLab's symbolic solver which found the following solution.
$$y(x)=C_1\frac{e^{\sqrt{B}x}}{x}-C_2\frac{e^{-\sqrt{B}x}}{2\sqrt{B}x}$$
Unofrtunately, the constant B takes both positive and negative values, but since the ODE is derived from a physical problem I'd like the solution to always be real.
Any suggestion/comment is highly appreciated.

Comment: What does Matlab say if you replace $-B$ by $+B$ ?

Comment: It looks like none of the answers below actually answered your query. Assuming the symbolic solver solution is correct, if $B$ is negative, then $y$ is complex. When $B$ is positive, $y$ is real. If you want the solution to always be real, then you _must_ have $B > 0$. Note that if $B$ is to smoothly change from positive (negative) to negative (positive) values, then it must go through $B = 0$, which has a qualitatively different solution to the one you got from Matlab.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Try the substitution
\begin{equation}
y(x) = \frac{z(x)}{x}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

$$y''+\frac{2}{x}y'-\beta y=0$$
$$xy''+{2}y'-\beta xy=0$$
Substitute $z=\sqrt \beta x  ( \beta >0)$:
$$x{\beta} y''(z)+{2}{\sqrt {\beta}}y'(z)-\beta xy(z)=0$$
$$z y''+2y'-zy=0$$
$$(zy)''-zy=0$$
Charactristic polynomial is:
$$r^2-1=0 \implies r= \pm 1$$
$$\implies zy=c_1e^{-z}+c_2e^{z}$$
$$\boxed {y(x)=\dfrac {1}{x} \left (k_1e^{-\sqrt {\beta}x}+k_2e^{\sqrt {\beta}x} \right)}$$

---

For  $\beta <0 $ :
$$xy''+{2}y'+\alpha xy=0$$
Where $\alpha=-\beta $.
Substitute $z=\sqrt \alpha x $:
$$x{\alpha} y''(z)+{2}{\sqrt {\alpha}}y'(z)+\alpha xy(z)=0$$
$$z y''+2y'+zy=0$$
$$(zy)''+zy=0$$
$$ \implies r^2+1=0 \implies r=\pm i$$
$$\implies zy=c_1\cos z+c_2 \sin z$$
Unsubstitute $z= \sqrt {\alpha } x$.
$$\boxed {y(x)=\dfrac {1}{x} \left (k_1\cos {(\sqrt {\alpha}x)}+k_2 \sin ({\sqrt {\alpha}x}) \right)}$$

Answer (score 0):

That solution is also valid for negative $B$, although it will use complex numbers. To find the solution without complex numbers using that solution, I first made the substitution $\frac{C_2}{2\sqrt{B}} \to C_2$ just for convenience: $$y(x)=\frac{C_1e^{\sqrt{B}x} - C_2e^{-\sqrt{B}x}}{x}$$

Then for negative $B$, this is $$\frac{C_1e^{i\sqrt{-B}x} - C_2e^{-i\sqrt{-B}x}}{x}$$

Using that $e^{ix} = \cos(x)+i\sin(x)$, this becomes $$\frac{C_1\left(\cos(x\sqrt{-B}) + i\sin(x\sqrt{-B})\right) - C_2\left(\cos(x\sqrt{-B}) - i\sin(x\sqrt{-B})\right)}{x}$$

Making the substitution $C_1 - C_2 = c_1$ and $iC_1 + iC_2 = c_2$ makes it $$\frac{c_1\cos(x\sqrt{-B}) + c_2\sin(x\sqrt{-B})}{x}$$